# GCP: Can I use Cloud Build to perform CI/CD tasks in VM instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Cloud Platform and exploring its CI/CD tools.

I have an app deployed in a VM instance and I'm wondering if I can use GCP's tool such as Cloud Build to do CI/CD instead of using Jenkins.

From what I've learned over several resources, Cloud Build seems to be a nice tool for Cloud Run (deploying Docker images) and Cloud Functions.

Can I use it for apps deployed in VM instances?

When you create a job in Cloud Build, you set up a `cloudbuild.yaml` file in which you specify the build steps. How to write the step such that it will go into a linux VM, log in as a particular user, `cd` into a directory, pull the master branch of the project repo, and start running the `main.py` (say it's a python project)?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a workflow that will allow you to deploy and perform tasks in an GCE Instance.
I found a great example in the Google Cloud Platform  [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/remote-builder) repository, that may be what you are looking for:

- It will create a temporary SSH key in  your Container Builder workspace.
- Then, an Instance will be launched.
- The workspace will be copied to the Instance previously launched.
- A command will run inside that Instance's workspace.

Keep in mind that you will need to create an appropriate IAM role, with permissions to create and destroy Compute Engine instances:

```
export PROJECT=$(gcloud info --format='value(config.project)')
export PROJECT_NUMBER=$(gcloud projects describe $PROJECT --format 'value(projectNumber)')
export CB_SA_EMAIL=$PROJECT_NUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
gcloud services enable cloudbuild.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable compute.googleapis.com
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT --member=serviceAccount:$CB_SA_EMAIL --role='roles/iam.serviceAccountUser' --role='roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1' --role='roles/iam.serviceAccountActor'
```

Then, you should configure your build steps, for example if you want to run your python application:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/remote-builder
  env:
    - COMMAND=sudo python3 main.py
```

Regards.